# "bad password" message when trying to use my SSH key, even though the password matches what's in my keychain

Tags: github, ssh, passwords, keychain, ssh-keys

For reference I'm using a MacBook pro, running El Capitan 10.11.16.

I'm trying to push an existing local git repo to a new remote github repo. When I try to, I'm prompted to enter the password for my SSH key (3 times). After doing this, I get a message saying "Permission denied (publickey)". I tried this a handful of times with the same result.

I ran 'eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"', then tried both 'ssh-add -l' and 'ssh-add -l -E md5'. The response was 'The agent has no identities.' for both.

I used the keychain access app to get the password for my key (id_rsa). It's exactly what I was typing when prompted for my password.

I tried changing the password using ssh-keygen. When prompted for my old password, I entered the password in my keychain but kept getting a "bad password" error.

I can still push to my other remote github repositories. I can also use ssh to connect to a remote server I'm renting.

I really have no idea what's going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to, I'm prompted to enter the password for my SSH key (3 times).

That is the password of the account you are using when ssh'ing:

```
ssh xxx@amachine
    ^^^
     ^
     |- xxx's password
```

That is because ssh tries to offer your `id_rsa.pub` public key, but said public key is not douns in `~xxx/.ssh/authrozied_keys` on the remote machine '`amachine`'.
So ssh fallback to the username(`xxx`)/password authentication method.

> I used the keychain access app to get the password for my key (`id_rsa`).

Here, the "password for my key (`id_rsa`)" in question actually refers to a private key *passphrase*.
So unless you have generate your private key with a passphrase, no need to enter the one of your keychain.

> I can still push to my other remote github repositories.

That is because your same [public key has been added to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

> I'm trying to push an existing local git repo to a new remote github repo

Double check the ssh url used: it needs to be like with

```
git@github.com:<user>/<repo>
```